# How I could push to my own view without having to instance itself everytime I do it

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

Im instantiating my own view class everytime I push to it.

```
MyOwnView *newSameView = [[MyOwnView alloc]initWithNibName:nil
 bundle:NULL];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:MyOwnView
    animated:YES];
```

Comment: What's the problem? What you are doing is normal.

Comment: But doesnt it alloc more memory everytime I instance it?

Comment: Only if you never pop the view controller off of the nav stack.

Comment: If you need to hold a reference, you could make `MyOwnView` a subclass of a simple `UIViewController`, push to `MyOwnView` from that parent, which also includes a property that holds the reference to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked "But doesnt it alloc more memory everytime I instance it?" The answer is no. It allocates DIFFERENT memory every time you create an instance, but that memory is freed when you pop the view controller off the stack.

If you want to keep an instance of your MyOwnViewController class, then create a property that "lazy loads" a view controller, and use that.

If this is your property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyOwnViewController * myVC;
```

The getter would look something like this:

```
-(MyOwnViewController *) myVC;
{
  if (_myVC == nil)
    _myVC = [[MyOwnViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
  return _myVC;
}
```

Then you can write the code that pushes the view controller like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: self.myVC animated:YES];
```

The good thing about this is that you only create a single instance of your MyOwnViewController. The down-side is that it never gets freed as long as the view controller that creates it lives, unless you explicitly set it to nil. If at some point you don't need it any more, it will take up extra memory (again, unless you manually set the property to nil)

The other approach creates a new copy of MyOwnViewController every time it's needed, and then deallocates it as soon as it's popped. You do more work creating/destroying MyOwnViewController instances, but they don't take up memory when you're not using them.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the reference to your ViewController in a private property of the class that performs pushes. You should initialize it only once in `viewDidLoad` and then using it.